# PhoneGap not Working on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, android-debug

I'm trying to Run PhoneGap on my android Device "Galaxy Tab 10.1" and it's not working .. i following the next steps, but not working ...

1. Putting cordova-2.7.0.jar at libs directory.
2. putting cordova-2.7.0.js at assets/www directory.
3. include xml directory at res directory.

Then i changed my Activity class to:

```
package ezz.apps.welcomephonegap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    super.loadUrl("file:///Users/ahmed/Documents/workspace/WelcomePhoneGap/assets/www/index.html",1000);
    }

}
```

and my index.html look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>PhoneGap</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
       <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ezz.apps.welcomephonegap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ezzapps.welcomephonegap.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
        <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
    </activity>
  </application>

    <supports-screens
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:resizeable="true"
     android:anyDensity="true"
    />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

   </manifest>
```

So... there are any thing i miss it.. or why it doesn't work ...????

Comment: chek this vedio on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yOedWb7dfc

Comment: There is an additional issue with the package name; see "p.s." below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the app is on your device or emulator, this path is unknown (`/Users/...`):

```
super.loadUrl("file:///Users/ahmed/Documents/workspace/WelcomePhoneGap/assets/www/index.html",1000);
```

As far as I know it has to be:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

**p.s.** while looking once more at it I saw another issue: you wrote ...

```
<activity android:name="com.ezzapps.welcomephonegap.MainActivity" ...
```

in your manifest, though your activity is in package `ezz.apps.welcomephonegap` - so it should be:

```
<activity android:name="ezz.apps.welcomephonegap.MainActivity" ...
```

Cheers!

Comment: i tried but still not working Eclipse show me this error Source Not found

Comment: Where does Eclipse show this? The path is just a string, Eclipse shouldn't care about this. Or do you mean the logcat? Have you put the `index.html` into the folder _<project root>_ `/assets/www/`? P.s. if you have a logcat error please paste it into your question - it might be helpful.